# Regex for a number between 0 and 9.99

Tags: regex

How to write a regex to match:
- Positive numbers only
- between 0 and 9.99 (10.00 is not allowed)
- dot or comma can be used.

Comment: all samples found here in SO not meet my criteria.

Comment: However, there are tons of similar questions and you could have already written an almost working pattern. So, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, provided your number is not at the beginning of the string.

```
\D\d(?:[\.,]\d+)
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/s3tIr4/

> Explanation
>
> \D matches any character that\'s not a digit (equal to [^0-9])
>
> \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>
> Non-capturing group (?:[.,]\d+)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [.,]
>
> \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
>
> , matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
>
> \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>
> + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)